# How to define gluon application version

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I want to put the application version to my gluon application. but I don't know how to do. Do I need to create service for that?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple approach, that doesn't required a service, but it can lead to errors:

You can maintain a version code/version number for Android in the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              package="your.package" 
              android:versionCode="1.1.0" 
              android:versionName="1.1.0">
```

The same on iOS, in the Default-Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>your.bundle.identifier</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1.1.0</string>
```

And finally you can keep a static field in your code:

```
public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.1.0";
```

that you can access from the `NavigationDrawer`, for instance.

However this requires manual updating every time you make a new release.

To avoid errors, you can set some CI job that does it for you. See for instance this [commit](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/commit/4db73db354d6ae66087650490432eab3ae2b1092), that it is part of the release job of a mobile app.

**Charm Down Service**

However, a more definitive way of avoiding mismatches between the released versions and the variable in your code is by adding a service that directly reads those versions.

Something like this:

**VersionService.java**

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins;

public interface VersionService {

    String getVersionName();

}
```

**VersionServiceFactory.java**

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins;

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.DefaultServiceFactory;

public class VersionServiceFactory extends DefaultServiceFactory<VersionService> {

    public VersionServiceFactory() {
        super(VersionService.class);
    }

}
```

Android package, under `src/android/java`:

**AndroidVersionService.java**

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.VersionService;
import javafxports.android.FXActivity;

public class AndroidVersionService implements VersionService {

    @Override
    public String getVersionName() {
        try {
            return FXActivity.getInstance().getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(FXActivity.getInstance().getPackageName(), 0)
                    .versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) { }
        return "";
    }

}
```

IOS package, under `src/ios/java`:

**IOSVersionService.java**

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.ios;

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.VersionService;

public class IOSVersionService implements VersionService {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Version");
    }

    @Override
    public String getVersionName() {
        return getNativeVersion();
    }

    private static native String getNativeVersion();

}
```

Under `src/ios/native`:

**Version.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include "jni.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JNI_OnLoad_Version(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
{
#ifdef JNI_VERSION_1_8
    //min. returned JNI_VERSION required by JDK8 for builtin libraries
    JNIEnv *env;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_8) != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_8;
#else
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
#endif
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_gluonhq_charm_down_plugins_ios_IOSVersionService_getNativeVersion
(JNIEnv *env, jclass jClass)
{
    NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, [version cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
}
```

Build files, at root level:

**ios-build.gradle**

```
if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        exec {
            args '-version', '-sdk', 'iphoneos', 'SDKVersion'
            executable 'xcodebuild'
            standardOutput = os
        }
        ext.IOS_VERSION = os.toString().trim()
    }
} else {
    ext.IOS_VERSION = ""
}
ext.IS_DEBUG_NATIVE = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("IS_DEBUG_NATIVE", "false"))

def sdkPath(String platform) {
    return "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/${platform}.platform/Developer/SDKs/${platform}${IOS_VERSION}.sdk";
}

ext.xcodebuildIOS = {buildDir, projectDir, name ->

    if (!file(sdkPath('iPhoneOS')).exists()) {
        println "Skipping xcodebuild"
        return
    }

    // define statics do being able to configure the input/output files on the task
    // for faster builds if nothing changed
    def buildSystems = ["iPhoneOS+arm64",
                        "iPhoneOS+armv7",
                        "iPhoneSimulator+i386",
                        "iPhoneSimulator+x86_64"]
    def linkerOutputs = []

    def lipoOutput = "$buildDir/native/lib${name}.a"

    def nativeSources = ["$projectDir/src/ios/native/${name}.m"]

    // the actual task action
    buildSystems.each { buildSystem ->

        def (platform, arch) = buildSystem.tokenize("+");

        def compileOutput = "$buildDir/native/$arch"
        def compileOutputs = ["$buildDir/native/$arch/${name}.o"]

        def linkerOutput = "$buildDir/native/$arch/lib${name}.a"

        new File(compileOutput).mkdirs();

        def clangArgs = [
                "-x", "objective-c",
                "-miphoneos-version-min=6.0",
                "-fmessage-length=0",
                "-std=c99",
                "-fno-common",
                "-Wall",
                "-fno-strict-aliasing",
                "-fwrapv",
                "-fpascal-strings",
                "-fobjc-abi-version=2",
                "-fobjc-legacy-dispatch",
                "-I" + System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/include",
                "-I" + System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/include/darwin",
                "-c",
                IS_DEBUG_NATIVE ? ["-O0", "-DDEBUG", "-g"] : ["-O3", "-DNDEBUG"],
                "-arch", arch,
                "-isysroot",
                sdkPath(platform),
                nativeSources].flatten()
        // "-o", compileOutput,

        def linkerArgs = [
                "-static",
                "-framework", "Foundation",
                "-framework", "CoreGraphics",
                "-framework", "CoreBluetooth",
                "-framework", "CoreLocation",
                "-framework", "CoreMotion",
                "-framework", "CoreText",
                "-framework", "UIKit",
                "-framework", "QuartzCore",
                "-framework", "OpenGLES",
                "-framework", "UserNotifications",
                "-arch_only", arch,
                "-syslibroot", sdkPath(platform),
                "-L${sdkPath(platform)}/usr/lib",
                "-o", linkerOutput,
                compileOutputs
        ].flatten()

        // execute compiler
        exec {
            executable "clang"
            args clangArgs
            workingDir compileOutput
        }

        // execute linker
        exec {
            executable "libtool"
            args linkerArgs
            workingDir compileOutput
        }

        linkerOutputs.add(linkerOutput)
    }

    def lipoArgs = [
            "-create",
            linkerOutputs,
            "-o",
            lipoOutput
    ].flatten();

    // execute lipo to combine all linker output in one archive
    exec {
        executable "lipo"
        args lipoArgs
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply from: 'ios-build.gradle'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'your.main.class'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.11'
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}

task xcodebuild {
    doLast {
        xcodebuildIOS("$project.buildDir","$project.projectDir", "Version")
    }
}

task installNativeLib (type:Copy, dependsOn: xcodebuild) {
    from("$project.buildDir/native")
    into("src/ios/jniLibs")
    include("*.a")
}
```

Before deploying to iOS, run:

```
./gradlew installNativeLib
```

**Service use**

Finally, you can use the service anywhere in your code:

```
String version = Services.get(VersionService.class)
            .map(VersionService::getVersionName)
            .orElse(""));
```